# Powershell script integrity

Tags: powershell, data-integrity

Trying to find a method of which one can verify that the running script has been modified. I was thinking I could sign the script and have it check itself, however the only protection is having all the execution policy set to only run with signed scripts, which in some locations might not be the case.

I also thought about compiling the script but didn't know really what that would actually achieve...

Trying to keep it as dependant free as possible for compatibility reasons, so lowest version of Powershell and less dependent on external libraries.

Comment: I don't think you can get there from here.  If the script can be modified then any self-validation routine within the script is useless, since it can be modified as well.

Comment: Echo what Thor's Hammer said. Why do you need this? What problem are you trying to fix or mitigate?

Comment: If you can be sure you control the session before anything nefarious can happen, you can use `Set-ExecutionPolicy AllSigned -Scope Process` to enforce signed scripts even if the environment normally does not. But obviously, doing this in a script that is subject to modification itself is pointless. You need somewhere trusted to start from.

Comment: @Matt I am deploying a script into customer environments where it will gather some details and report them back. Hence I can't guarantee the environment setup and have to rely on own verification methods.

Answer (score 1):

An open script is very hard to secure. There are a few options available.

1: Compile the script into an executable. This would prevent most users from knowing how to modify the script.

2: Minify/Uglify the script so that it becomes very difficult to understand or modify without breaking.

3: As you mentioned signing the script may help depending on the environment.

4: Use one of the above methods and have the script check back with a server to verify the integrity of the script.

None of those are 100% foolproof, but it does give you options depending on the environment the script is running in.

Here is an example of an app that will obfuscate a PowerShell script: [PowerShell Obfuscator](http://www.powertheshell.com/powershell-obfuscator/)

Comment: Thanks, do you know of a Python library that can do obsfuscation? I'm basically building the script on a per client basis in a python script

Comment: I don't use Python so I wouldn't know of a library to use. I did find a github project for Powershell obfuscation doing a little searching: https://github.com/danielbohannon/Invoke-Obfuscation. That will let you obfuscate a powershell script using powershell.

Comment: I did find another Python minifier as well: https://liftoff.github.io/pyminifier/. That one is strictly for python scripts. You may be able to combine the two for full obfuscation...

Comment: Sorry, I was actually looking for a python library to minify Powershell scripts...